# Range-For loop over a string adding a null or empty char at the end

Tags: c++

Here is a loop that goes through each character in `"(Level:"`. It adds something to the end which is messing up the rest of my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Output:" << std::endl;
    for (char letter : "(Level:") {
        std::cout << "'" << letter << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
'('
'L'
'e'
'v'
'e'
'l'
':'
''
```

I'm new to C++ and I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: In C/C++, strings are null terminated _(i.e. will have a value of zero at the end of the string)_. You are seeing the null terminating character

Comment: @robthebloke to be more exact, C-style string pointers, and string **literals** (as in this case), are null terminated. C++-style strings (the `std::(w|u8|u16|u32)string` classes) are not. Well, they have a null terminator present, but it is not counted towards the string's size or iterators. So, for instance, a range-for loop over a `std::string` would not include the null terminator in the iteration.

Comment: Add `using std::literals::operator""s;` before the for loop and change `"(Level:"` to `"(Level:"s`

Comment: You can use `string_view` to get rid of the null terminal at the end, like `for (char letter : std::string_view("(Level:"))`.

Comment: Please don't add answers to questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"(Level:"` has type `const char[8]`, and is equivalent to `{ '(', 'L', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'l', ':', '\0' }`.

You can easily see this is the case by casting the letter to `int` before printing. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sM54Yq8hP)

This happens, because string literals (anything `"..."`) are C-strings, which are zero terminated. If you want strings to have a size instead of a zero terminator, you can use a `string_view` literal:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Output:" << std::endl;
    for (char letter : "(Level:"sv) {
        std::cout << "'" << letter << "' (" << static_cast<int>(letter) << ")\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[See the result](https://godbolt.org/z/7aGErqM5Y)

Answer (score 0):

Cause the strings in C++ are all ended with '\0', we can't see it but it really exists. This hidden '\0' can marks the end of a string and can be read by your 'for' statement. You can add an 'if' statement in your 'for' statement to deal with '\0'.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Output:" << std::endl;
    for (char letter : "(Level:") {
        if (letter != '\0')
            std::cout << "'" << letter << "'" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```